# F# bit reversal permutation

Tags: .net, f#, bit-manipulation, bit

I am trying to do a bit reversal permutation in F#.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit-reversal_permutation

I know how to do this in Python:

```
def bitrev(x, bits):
    y = 0
    for i in range(bits):
        y = (y << 1) | (x & 1)
        x >>= 1
    return y
```

which should return the following list if given, say, bits = 4 for values in the range of 0-15: 
`0 8 4 12 2 10 6 14 1 9 5 13 3 11 7 15`

How can I accomplish this without mutable values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always go the imperative way and do a direct translation from Python:

```
let bitrev x bits =
    let mutable x = x
    let mutable y = 0
    for i in 1..bits do
        y <- (y <<< 1) ||| (x &&& 1)
        x <- x >>> 1
    y
```

Which you run like this:

```
[0..15]
|> List.map (fun n -> bitrev n 4)
|> printfn "%A"

// [0; 8; 4; 12; 2; 10; 6; 14; 1; 9; 5; 13; 3; 11; 7; 15]
```

The functional way with immutability would be like this:

```
let bitrev x bits =
    let rec bitrevR x bits y =
        match bits with
        | 0 -> y
        | _ ->
        bitrevR (x >>> 1) (bits - 1)  ((y <<< 1) ||| (x &&& 1))
    bitrevR x bits 0
```

The internal representations for numbers between 0..15 is 4 bits:

```
binary  decimal
  0000  =  0
  0001  =  1
  0010  =  2
  0011  =  3
  0100  =  4
  0101  =  5
  0110  =  6
  0111  =  7
  1000  =  8
  1001  =  9
  1010  = 10
  1011  = 11
  1100  = 12
  1101  = 13
  1110  = 14
  1111  = 15
```

which reversed look like this:

```
binary  decimal
0000  =  0   <->   0000 =  0
0001  =  1   <->   1000 =  8
0010  =  2   <->   0100 =  4
0011  =  3   <->   1100 = 12
0100  =  4   <->   0010 =  2
0101  =  5   <->   1010 = 10
0110  =  6   <->   0110 =  6
0111  =  7   <->   1110 = 14
1000  =  8   <->   0001 =  1
1001  =  9   <->   1001 =  9
1010  = 10   <->   0101 =  5
1011  = 11   <->   1101 = 13
1100  = 12   <->   0011 =  3
1101  = 13   <->   1011 = 11
1110  = 14   <->   0111 =  7
1111  = 15   <->   1111 = 15
```

Comment: So I actually did an imperative translation *exactly* like yours, but for whatever reason, it only works for me if bits = 3... Can you think of a reason why that might be? I ended up iterating from `1..bits-1`.

Comment: Thanks for the functional version too! You saved me a huge amount of stress - I wish I could upvote more.

Comment: I just changed the bits range  from 0..3 to 1..4 the whole point is to do the internal shift of the bits 4 times.

Comment: I see! So the iterator values don't matter, so long as you're engaging 4 iterations.

Answer (score 0):

In case you were not only interested in individual elements `a(m, k)` where `m < 2^k` and `k = 0, 1, 2, ...`, but in the involutions as larger blocks of the sequence [A030109](https://oeis.org/A030109) in the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/): A generator is easily written for it.

```
let a030109 =
    seq[0] |> Seq.unfold (fun xs ->
        let ys = Seq.map ((*) 2) xs
        let zs = Seq.map ((+) 1) ys
        Some(xs, Seq.append ys zs) )
    |> Seq.concat

a030109
|> Seq.skip (pown 2 4 - 1)
|> Seq.take (pown 2 4)
|> Seq.toList
// val it : int list = [0; 8; 4; 12; 2; 10; 6; 14; 1; 9; 5; 13; 3; 11; 7; 15]
```